# Add Postgresql server to postgres-common

Tags: postgresql

I've created `postgresql` cluster using `initdb`. Now I can't use it with common tools.
Can i somehow add this cluster or if no, how can i delete it to create new one with `pg_createcluster`. I know there's a `DROP SERVER` command but it requires a name and i don't know how to look it up.

Comment: What do you mean with "common tools"?

Comment: I mean postgresql-common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain `initdb` creates a PostgreSQL cluster in the normal fashion, with all files contained in a single directory. Consequently, it is very easy to get rid of that new cluster: just delete the created directory and all files in it.